# Unique values count in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have data like this:

```
Date | Location  | Item
-----------------------
1    | x         | a 
1    | x         | b 
1    | x         | a 
2    | b         | a
```

and I'd like to extract unique values of rows and add a column for number of occurence

I tried this command but it failed:

```
p=df3.groupby(['date', 'location', 'item']).count()
```

Result=

```
Date | Location  | Item | Occurences
------------------------------------
1    | x         | a    | 2
1    | x         | b    | 1 
2    | b         | a    | 1
```

Comment: perhaps `.size()` instead of `.count()` ?  (also, as a suggestion, including a small executable/code example would make it easier to follow what you've tried and what you're seeing.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.size()`:

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Location', 'Item']).size().rename('Ocurrences').to_frame().reset_index()

    Date    Location    Item    Ocurrences
0   1           x          a    2
1   1           x          b    1
2   2           b          a    1
```